# IST time conversion to HHH:MM

Tags: javascript

"Wed Jun 06 1900 00:08:50 GMT+0530 (IST)" need to convert into Hours and Min "HHH:MM"

```
var date = new Date(inputtime);
var pp=date.toString();

var date = new Date(inputtime);
var pp=date.toString();
```

Comment: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: What exactly is the `HHH:MM` value of `Wed Jun 06 1900 00:08:50 GMT+0530 (IST)`?

Comment: Do you want to keep the time zone used in the inputtime or use default given from Date (Which is local)

Answer (score 0):

You can try momentjs

```
var date = new Date(inputtime);
var pp=moment(inputtime, "HH:mm:ss a");
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

You can use below plain javascript code to get `HH:mm` (24-hour time), or expand it to get `HH:mm:ss` etc. if you wish:

```js
let date = new Date("Wed Jun 06 1900 00:08:50");
let timeStr = date.toLocaleTimeString("en-GB", {hour12:false, hour:"2-digit",minute:"2-digit", second:"2-digit"}) //? 
let arr2 = timeStr.split(":") //? ['00', '08', '50']
let HH = arr2[0]; //00 
let mm = arr2[1]; //08

let HHmm = `${HH}:${mm}`//"00:08"

console.log(HHmm) //00:08
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out I would also highly recommend momentjs.

However, if you for some reason can not use libraries the following would work:

```
var inputtime = "Wed Jun 06 1900 00:08:50 GMT+0530 (IST)";
var date = new Date(inputtime);
var formatted = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes();
```

The following could also be used if you want to keep leading zeroes:

```
var inputtime = "Wed Jun 06 1900 00:08:50 GMT+0530 (IST)";
var date = new Date(inputtime);
var formatted = leadingZeroes(date.getHours()) + ":" + leadingZeroes(date.getMinutes());

function leadingZeroes(n) {
  return (n <= 9 ? "0" : "") + n;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it is still not giving the exact value. when i read the value from google sheet i get 'Thu Jul 12 1900 16:08:50 GMT+0530 (IST)'  so i need to convert this value in HHH and  MM then actual value in google sheet is '4672:00'